# Update only few columns in Microsoft Flow

Tags: workflow, item, flow

I am trying to use the activity "Updated Item in SharePoint list" activity in the Microsoft flow catalogue.

The case is I want to only update a few fields for example a Status **column**.

The problem is that flow sets all other fields either to blank or its default value unless you specify to update all other properties to be updated, which I **dont** want to.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the item variable to set it to current value. It happens to me on some but not all field types.

Comment: Item variable would have worked fine if the item being updated, and the item with which the flow is being triggered would have been same.But they are different.